# How do i load a different image for every member in javafx?

Tags: java, image, javafx

Im working on a membership manager in Java and for every member i want it to load a different picture from a a specific folder.

The problem is that it dosent work. It always loads the default image which is used if that member does not have a profile picture.

Here is the code:

```
protected Image loadMemberImage(String path){
    Image image;
    File file = new File(path);

    System.out.println(path);

    if(file.exists()){
        image = new Image(path);
    }
    else {
        image = new Image("res/memberdata/default.png");
    }

    return image;
}
```

this code always loads the default image even if the user has  a profile picture

i also tried this :

```
        if(!file.exists()){
```

this loads the image if it exists for some reason, but it does not change to the default picture if i later select a user that has none.

PS: the system out is there to check if it gets the right path which it does.

Comment: File paths and urls are different. Try not mixing them. If the `String` contains a url, you could use nio to check, if the file exists: `Path p = Paths.get(new URL(path).toURI()); if (Files.exists(p)) ...` if not post some example paths print to the console... furthermore when is the method used? are you sure it's called for every member and the `image` property of the `ImageView` that is supposed to show the image is modified?

Comment: You need to post enough code that duplicates your problem.